# Code::Blocks C++ autocompletion not working within #ifdef blocks

Tags: c++, parsing, autocomplete, codeblocks, conditional-compilation

Problem:

---

**I am unable to get any local auto-completion within project level #ifdef blocks.**

*Right click > find declaration, implementation, etc also does not work within this file for local declarations.*

Example:

---

Variable types and functions not declared inside the `#ifdef` block do have working auto-complete:

```
// greater than 3 letters to make sure auto-complete should trigger

AClass aName;  // < this class will auto-complete
aName.aMethod; // < this will auto-complete

#ifdef DEFBLOCK
    AClass bName;  // < this class will auto-complete
    bName.aMethod; // < this will not auto-complete (neither var nor method)
#endif
```

What I've Tried/Other Info:

---

After manually re-parsing from the project menu the Code::Blocks log only says the project was removed from the parser and never re-added. Specifically re-parsing the file in question also doesn't work and produces no log output.

The entire project builds successfully. I've restarted Code::Blocks and rebooted the machine. Code::Blocks version is 13.12, OS is Xubuntu 14.04.

I've looked over the other similar questions here but they either lack sufficient information, have no workable answer and or don't necessarily pertain to my specific problem.

Settings:

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
Replacement tokens are default.

How can I get it to parse within the `#ifdef` block?

Comment: Do you use some C++11 features in this file?

Comment: Good question... Not that I know of. Any quick way to check?

Comment: This is a bit of a messy story that lists a lot of problems but doesn't really give any information. Could you provide concrete reproduction steps?

Comment: Sorry it was a work in progress. Is that better? I had two false positives amidst trying to find the real problem.